# expandableRowTemplate url forces angular reload via routing

Tags: angularjs, grid

I've searched and searched, but can't find a solution to the expandable grid. Basically, when I click on the grid the expandable row seems to reload angular via the ui routing.

Unfortunately, all the plunker examples have the files in the same location, so the examples work. None of the examples shows what happens if your using ui routing.

```
    vm.gridOptions = {
        expandableRowTemplate: 'expandableRowTemplate.html',
        expandableRowHeight: 350,
    }
```

Please see image below

[expandableRow.html reloads angular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fdAo.png)

I'm really hoping someone can assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess we dont need ui routing for this, actually we are loading only the template we usually giving the full template path instead of loading from same path.

ex:
rowTemplate: 'views/folder-1/template/row.html'

Comment: Amazing, so simple, didn't even think about using the full path name as you've suggested.  Thank you so much